# shell script - redirection makes some information lost

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have a shell script that can enable ble device scan with the following command

```
timeout 10s hcitool lescan
```

By executing this script (say ble_scan), I can see the nearby devices shown on the terminal.

However, when I redirect it to the file and terminal

```
./ble_scan | tee test.log
```

I can't see the nearby devices shown on the screen anymore and log file as well.

```
 ./ble_scan 2>&1 | tee test.log
```

The above redirection also doesnt help, anything I go wrong here?

Comment: Some programs change behavior depending on whether stdout is a pipe or terminal. Looks like this one does, too.

Comment: @Jens yea, any idea to have a output file?

Comment: @Jens sorry I've just edited the question, add timeout before hcitool lescan, please reply if you have any idea to this.

Answer (score 1):

If the command behaves differently with file output, you can run it within `script`.

```
script test.log
#=> Script started, output file is test.log
./ble_scan
# lots of output here
exit 
#=> Script done, output file is test.log
```

Note that the file will include terminal-specific characters like carriage returns not normally captured in output redirects.

Comment: Mark, in the ble_scan, I use the timeout command to kill the hcitool lescan. I doubt the data is killed before the redirection. Any idea to this ?